# Is it possible to declare alias fields in Alloy?

Tags: alloy

In my current model, I am finding it helpful to define alias fields.  These are fields that are really just expressed as an expression of an existing field.  I recently discovered the = syntax for declarations, which makes this really easy:

```
sig Foo {}
sig Class {
    thing1 : Foo,
    thing2 : Foo,
    alias = thing1 + thing2
}
```

I can refer to `alias` in constraints, but not in other field declarations.  For example:

```
sig Foo {}
sig Class {
    thing1 : Foo,
    thing2 : Foo,
    alias = thing1 + thing2,
    reference : alias
}
```

results in `A syntax error has occurred: The name "alias" cannot be found.`

Is there a reason why I can't refer to `alias` in this context?

On a related note, is there any documentation on declaring fields using `=`?  I can't find it referenced anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: From looking at the source code, what I am calling alias fields are called defined fields.

Comment: What would be the difference if you replace the '=' with ':'? The fact that you can use '=' here was new to me.

Comment: `thing : Type` means that `thing` is the set of `type` singletons.  `thing = type` means that the set `thing` equals the set `type`.  I think it's like `thing : all type` but Alloy doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of the equals syntax in declarations. But you don't need it; just write your example like this instead

```
sig Foo {}
sig Class {
    thing1, thing2: Foo,
    alias: set Foo,
    reference: set alias
} {
    alias = thing1 + thing2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aliases were originally defined using let expressions.

I don't know if it still works in current Alloy implementations, but in Alloy 4, I'd write:

```
let  alias = thing1 + thing2

sig Foo {}
sig Class {
    thing1 : Foo,
    thing2 : Foo,
   
    reference : alias
}


run{}
```